# List is perpetually "null" (ASP MVC3)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, code-first

I'm working on my first project using ASP MVC3. My application is code first using entity framework 4.1 and SQL server CE.

The application is a document library. The main model is Document which is a path to a pdf file and a bunch of metadata.

I have a "replace" function in my controller that takes one Document record, moves the file to an archive location, and updates the database with information about the replacement.
I am trying to store a list of strings with the document that represent filepaths to older versions of the same document.

No matter what I cannot get this list, called ArchivedFilePaths, to be anything but "null".

Model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace DocLibrary.Models
{
    public class Document
    {
        public int DocumentId { get; set; }
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string DocumentCode { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string FileUrl { get; set; }
        public int FileSize { get; set; }
        public string FileSizeString { get; set; }
        public int Pages { get; set; }
        public string Creator { get; set; }
        public int Revision { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime LastModifiedDate { get; set; }
        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
        public List<String> ArchivedFilePaths { get; set; }
        public SoftwareVersion SoftwareVersion { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Replace(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                int id = Int32.Parse(Request["DocumentId"]);
                Document doc = docsDB.Documents.Find(id);


                //move the current version to the ~/Archive folder
                string current_path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Files"), Path.GetFileName(doc.FileUrl));
                string archiveFileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(doc.FileUrl) + "-" + doc.Revision.ToString() + ".pdf";
                string destination_path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Archive"), archiveFileName);
                System.IO.File.Move(current_path, destination_path);


                if (doc.ArchivedFilePaths == null)
                {
                    doc.ArchivedFilePaths = new List<String>();
                }
                doc.ArchivedFilePaths.Add(destination_path);

   //there are a bunch of statements that update the title, number of pages, etc. here, all of these work fine

                    try
                    {
                        docsDB.Entry(doc).State = EntityState.Modified;
                        docsDB.Logs.Add(new Log { LogDate = DateTime.Now, LogText = "Document replaced with a new version: " + doc.Title, });
                        docsDB.SaveChanges();
                        return RedirectToAction("Index");
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
            //if a file was not selected;
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
```

The Index view displays all of the files and their properties, including ArchivedFilePaths. After replacing a document with a new file, all of the items in the Document model update properly except ArchivedFilePaths.

If I inspect the list in VisualStudio, it is not null after the `doc.ArchivedFilePaths.Add` statement. So I don't believe the list is ever saved in the database and I suspect there is something wrong with my model. If I change it to a single string I can update it just fine.

Does anyone have any insight? Thanks.

Comment: Just as a side-note, your conditional to check if `ArchivedFilePaths` is `null` is, from a design perspective, in the wrong place.  It would be better to add a constructor to the `Document` class which initializes its values (such as initializing empty lists).  That way it would always be a valid instance of a list, no matter where you use it.

Comment: Also, what does `Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());` even _do_ in a web application?  Are you sure you're not swallowing exceptions here?

Comment: You're right. I updated the `Document` class to initialize the list as empty, thanks for pointing that out. Console.WriteLine prints the exception to the Visual Studio Output tab. Just to make sure though I got rid of it, but I'm not getting any exceptions. 

Now that the list is initialized it's just perpetually empty, not null.

Comment: Take out the catch block and see if you get an exception. I think you're swallowing one.